# Java Run command line error in Apache Ant 1.9.9

Tags: linux, apache, command-line, ant

I am using ant to compile and run a java program, the program is successfully compiled but on running the desired output.txt is not generating. Is something wrong with run command?

COMPILE:  ant -buildfile build.xml all

RUN: ant -buildfile build.xml run -Darg0=train_all_txt.txt -Darg1=output.txt

Code in build.xml :

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${BUILD}/jar/recommenderSystem.jar"  fork="true">
    <arg value="${arg0}"/>
    <arg value="${arg1}"/>
    <arg value="${arg2}"/>
    <arg value="${arg3}"/>
    <arg value="${arg4}"/>
    </java> 
</target>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors/any clues in verbose? execute using -v

Comment: Yes, ant output from your build will help.